# How to let Python try an alternate server if previous one throws an error

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Within my configuration file, database uri looks like this: `SQLALCHEMY_URI = f"postgresql://{USER}:{PASSWORD}@{SERVER}/{NAME}"`.

I want to use two different values for `SERVER`, depending on where to deploy the code - a default value, and another value in case previous one fails. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: You could use a `try:`/ `except:` statement. Put the first server in the `try: ` block and the second server in the `except:` block. Put the kind of error that you get after the `except` statement (before `:`).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using, for example, sqlalchemy package than code should look like:

```
import sqlalchemy

try:    
    SQLALCHEMY_URI = f"postgresql://{USER}:{PASSWORD}@{SERVER}/{NAME}"
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_URI)
except sqlalchemy.errors.TimeoutError:
    print('Connection error - using another server')   # or some log, alert, whatever you like
    SQLALCHEMY_URI = f"postgresql://{USER}:{PASSWORD}@{ANOTHER_SERVER}/{NAME}"
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_URI)
```